# XML elements need to be renamed using xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

XML elements "row" need to be renamed by "case" and "CKEY" need to be renamed by "key"

Source file: In this case containing row and ckey are the  XML elements i need to be     replaced as above mentioned

```
<DST>
<PQCallHistory>
<hostAddress>$$$$$$$</hostAddress>
<hostPort>$$$$$</hostPort>
<userID>$$$$$</userID>
<password>$$$$$</password>
<folder>
<CRDATTIM>2012112302.44.40.334480</CRDATTIM>
<RECORDCD>F</RECORDCD>
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
<CaseCount>10</CaseCount>
<lastCRDATTIM>2014040202.23.10.105840</lastCRDATTIM>
<row>
<CRDATTIM>2014061709.58.36.947900</CRDATTIM>
<CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
<RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
<UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
<STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
<STPTIM>2014061720.28.35.000000</STPTIM>
<CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
<CKEY>2014061709.58.36.947900C01</CKEY>
</row>
<row>
<CRDATTIM>2014061709.52.53.157900</CRDATTIM>
<CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
<RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
<UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
<STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
<STPTIM>2014061720.22.51.000000</STPTIM>
<CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
<CKEY>2014061709.52.53.157900C01</CKEY>
</row>
<row>
<CRDATTIM>2014061605.05.44.690900</CRDATTIM>
<CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
<RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
<UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
<STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
<STPTIM>2014061615.35.42.000000</STPTIM>
<CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
<CKEY>2014061605.05.44.690900C01</CKEY>
</row>
<row>
<CRDATTIM>2014061604.58.39.446900</CRDATTIM>
<CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
<RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
<UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
<STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
<STPTIM>2014061615.28.35.000000</STPTIM>
<CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
<CKEY>2014061604.58.39.446900C01</CKEY>
</row>
<row>
<CRDATTIM>2014061104.03.59.807840</CRDATTIM>
<CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
<RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
<UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
<STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
<STPTIM>2014061114.33.53.000000</STPTIM>
<CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
<CKEY>2014061104.03.59.807840C01</CKEY>
</row>          
</folder>
</PQCallHistory>
</DST>

Expected file : This is the file, What i expected.

<PQCallHistory>
<hostAddress>$$$$$$$$</hostAddress> 
<hostPort>$$$$$</hostPort> 
<userID>$$$$$$$</userID> 
<password>$$$$$</password> 
<folder>
<CRDATTIM>2012112302.44.40.334480</CRDATTIM> 
<RECORDCD>F</RECORDCD> 
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE> 
<CaseCount>10</CaseCount> 
<lastCRDATTIM>2014040202.23.10.105840</lastCRDATTIM> 
<case>
<CRDATTIM>2014052900.56.23.813840</CRDATTIM> 
<CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA> 
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE> 
<RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD> 
<UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD> 
<STATCD>CREATED</STATCD> 
<STPTIM>2014052911.26.20.000000</STPTIM> 
<CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD> 
<KEY>2014052900.56.23.813840C01</KEY> 
</case>
<case>
<CRDATTIM>2014052208.02.59.494840</CRDATTIM> 
<CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA> 
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE> 
<RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD> 
<UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD> 
<STATCD>CREATED</STATCD> 
<STPTIM>2014052218.32.46.000000</STPTIM> 
<CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD> 
<KEY>2014052208.02.59.494840C01</KEY> 
</case>
<case>
<CRDATTIM>2014042403.02.31.131840</CRDATTIM> 
<CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA> 
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE> 
<RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD> 
<UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD> 
<STATCD>CREATED</STATCD> 
<STPTIM>2014042413.32.23.000000</STPTIM> 
<CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD> 
<KEY>2014042403.02.31.131840C01</KEY> 
</case>
<case>
<CRDATTIM>2014040202.24.00.823840</CRDATTIM> 
<CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA> 
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE> 
<RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD> 
<UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD> 
<STATCD>CREATED</STATCD> 
<STPTIM>2014040212.53.58.000000</STPTIM> 
<CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD> 
<KEY>2014040202.24.00.823840C01</KEY> 
</case>
<case>
<CRDATTIM>2014040202.23.10.105840</CRDATTIM> 
<CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA> 
<CRNODE>01</CRNODE> 
<RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD> 
<UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD> 
<STATCD>CREATED</STATCD> 
<STPTIM>2014040212.53.08.000000</STPTIM> 
<CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD> 
<KEY>2014040202.23.10.105840C01</KEY> 
</case>
</folder>
</PQCallHistory>
</DST>
```

Can any one help me on this...

Comment: row element is dynamic which is generated from the spring channels according to that replacement should be done ..i am new to this concept please can any one help me on this...

Comment: Where is the XSL you tried?

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//PQ/PQCallHistory/folder/row">
<xsl:copy>
 <case><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />   </case>        
</xsl:copy>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: but "case" element is coming under the element of row, that is not i am expecting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this XSLT.. I've removed xsl:copy from your template and the expression contained "//PQ" but there was no such element in your input XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PQCallHistory/folder/row">
        <case>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </case>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is no need to write match="PQCallHistory/folder/row", instead match="row". Writing match="PQCallHistory/folder/row" works as constrain (match row provided is under PQCallHistory/folder). XSLT processor is reading XML tree and knows the location of row.

Comment: yes that aslo works ,but we are following strictly with xpath.